# Drupal : How to remove the <p> and <br> tag from content when using syntaxhighlighter

Tags: input-formats

**Used Version 7.14**

I am using [syntaxhighlighter](http://drupal.org/project/syntaxhighlighter)  for my website. But when I insert some code samples it always producing output with more `<p>` and `<br>` also content in single line as well .

I am done just copy paste the code from zend studio editor inside the syntaxhighlighter tag

I've searched over many forums and druapl site itself, but nothing works for me. Please advise me on this

See the picture below  for more

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer this 100% but my first hunch was "hrm, filter ordering" and look, the project page draws your attention to:

> Very important!!!: ordered the input format filters as follow:
>
> - HTML filter or Wysiwyg filter or whatever HTML filters you use. They must come before.
> - Syntax highlighter. This come after any and all filters that can modify content input.
> - Line break converter. This must be after, If you see <br/> at the end of every line in your output, then you know what's wrong.

Comment: I am getting `<br />` although the highlighter is the lowest in the queue. What to do ?